# Any oneline code to achieve "if let" and then comparison (e.g. String compare)?

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am doing code review on my colleague's Swift code and would like to refactor the following piece of code:

```
let status = JSON["status"]

if (status != nil && status as! String == "success") {
    ...
}
```

Can it be achieved using a single line of code?

I could only manage to make it like:

```
if let status = JSON["status"] as! String {
    if status == "success" {
```

I wish I could make it like:

```
if let status = JSON["status"] as! String == "success" {
```

But it does not compile... Can somebody help? Thanks. Is `guard` statement useful in this case?

I am actually a novice in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need optional binding in your case, just:

```
if JSON["status"] as? String == "success" {
    // ...
}
```

The value of `JSON["status"] as? String` is an optional string, 
and that can be compared directly with with a non-optional string.

Answer (score 3):

```
if let status = JSON["status"] as? String where status == "success" {
```

Also if you use the swiftyJSON library:

```
if let status = JSON["status"].string where status == "success" {
```

Edit: further explanation

When you write

```
if let status = JSON["success"] as? String
```

You'll get an unwrapped String, meaning that this will ALWAYS have a value, if you do the other thing it would be Optional("nil"), so when you use:

```
if let status = JSON["success"] where status as? String = ""
```

You will have an unwrapped JSON object, whether is a string is yet to be determined, so when you want to work with a certain object type (in this case string) you downcast it immediately at the "if let" part so that you can also use the string functions in case you want to ask for a bool (or some other check).

I have never actually downcasted after unwrapping the optional value but I'd imagine it can go wrong because you still have an optional object which might be nil and you really want to have a value before it.

Comment: But I got the error message of **Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'** for `if let status = JSON["status"] as! String where status == "success" {`

Comment: That's because you force the downcast with as!, but that's also an error on my part, you should use as? to make it a safe downcast

Comment: I have a further question: what is the difference between `if let status = JSON["status"] where status as? String == "success" {` and `if let status = JSON["status"] as? String where status == "success" {`? i.e. They differ in the timing of the casting.

Comment: I'll expand my answer

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3

Just in case others reach this question that don't have the OP's specific use case (haven't tried in previous swift versions). You can comma separate your unwrapping and conditions:

```
if let status = JSON["status"] as! String, status == "success" {
```